# isotropy of the cotangent lift of a group action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, classical-mechanics, symmetry, symplectic-geometry

Given a group action on a manifold (e.g. configuration space of coordinates), cotangent-lift it to the phase space (i.e. coordinates and momentum), which is the appropriate cotangent bundle of the base manifold.

For a point on the base, there is an isotropy that fixes the coordinate variable; I naively think that the isotropy of the lifted action for a point in the cotangent fiber should be a subgroup of the corresponding isotropy on the base because both coordinate and momentum variables would have to be fixed now.

It seems that the size of the isotropy for the lifted action would depend on the momentum component: for example, along the zero section in the cotangent bundle (i.e. zero momentum for any coordinate point), the isotropy remains the same; for a generic momentum value, however, it may become a proper subgroup.

In general, momentum may not be independent of coordinate for they usually have to satisfy constraints such as the hamilton equation. So if I wish to find out the isotropy for the cotangent-lifted action at a point in the phase space, would I have to first solve the constraints -- provided that it is possible -- to figure out which momentum point I am looking at and then compute the isotropy explicitly? Or are there general facts that relate the isotropy on the base and that for the cotangent lift?

Thank you!